# Draw minimum enclosing circle around a contour in EmguCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv

How to draw a minimum enclosing circle around a contour in EmguCV?. FindContours() method returns a set of points. But to draw the circle it asks for pointf. Is there a work around this? Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.  You will just have to convert the Contour into an array of PointF like this:

```
for (var contour = binaryImage.FindContours(CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
    RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_CCOMP, mem);
    contour != null;
    contour = contour.HNext)
    {
        //assuming you have a way of getting the index of 
        //point you wanted to extract from the current contour
        var index = 0;
        PointF[] pointfs = Array.ConvertAll(contour.ToArray(), 
            input => new PointF(input.X, input.Y));

        //just an example
        var circle = new CircleF(pointfs[index], 2.0f);
    }
```